# Replicate original behavior when overriding Python's __new__ method

Tags: python, overriding, new-operator

Say I have the following classes

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = coords

class Line:
    def __init__(self, coords_A, coords_B):
        self.A = coords_A
        self.B = coords_B
```

and I want to get a `Point` when instantiating a `Line` with `coords_A == coords_B`. My understanding is that I can do this by overriding `__new__`. Here's what I tried:

```py
class Line:
    def __new__(cls, coords_A, coords_B):
        if coords_A == coords_B:
            return Point(coords_A)
        return super().__new__(cls, coords_A, coords_B)
        
    def __init__(self, coords_A, coords_B):
        self.A = coords_A
        self.B = coords_B
```

However, this does not work (calling `Line(1, 1)` does what I want, but `Line(1, 2)` raises a `TypeError`). It shouldn't either, After all I don't really want to call the `__new__` method of the parent class, I just want to replicate the original behavior of `Line.__new__`. How do I do this?

Comment: Error message: `TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = coords


class Line:
    def __new__(cls, coords_A, coords_B):
        if coords_A == coords_B:
            return Point(coords_A)
        return super(Line, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, coords_A, coords_B):
        self.A = coords_A
        self.B = coords_B
```